# Binding functions within service layer to template

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to separate out the service related functions from the login page component and I am currently getting some errors along the lines of `self.context.logout is not a function`. Below, I am trying to inject the loginService into the loginPage and then bind some of the functions within the service to my login template. Any ideas why I am getting these errors? thanks in advance!

LoginService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor logic');
    }

    checkLoginStatus() {
        console.log('login logic');
    }

    logout() {
        console.log('logout logic');
    }
}
```

LoginComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  providers: [LoginService]
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(loginService : LoginService) {

  }

}
```

Template File

```
<button class="login-button" on-tap="loginService.checkLoginStatus()">
  Log In 
</button>
<button class="login-button" on-tap="loginService.logout()">
  Log Out 
</button>
```

Comment: Also, it looks like you mistyped `@Injectable()` decorator for `LoginService` - I don't think it will work with `;` and without `@`

Comment: good calll ;)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the service in the constructor an access modifier, or else it is only scoped to the constructor

```
// constructor(loginService : LoginService)
constructor(public loginService : LoginService)
```

Comment: Ha, that's just fantastic, thanks for the help :) what is the default access modifier for angular2 when one isn't specified? is it private?

Comment: I guess "only to constructor" lol. I don't know what it's called, if it even has  a name. It's definitely not `private` as even a private modifier gives access to the template. Remember there are no such things as access modiifers in JS, so when the TypeScript is compiled, the modfier is gone. So the template can still access a private variable

Comment: what do you mean by the template can still access a private variable? what's the point of making it private then?

Comment: Yeah the modifier is just shorthand for declaring the variable in the class and assigning it in the constructor (TypeScript does this for use behind the scenes). I forgot about that. Without the modifier, the property is not added to the class by TypeScript

Comment: _"what do you mean by the template can still access a private variable?"_ because there is no public or private in JS, which is what the typescript is compiled to. That means it's accessible at runtime, but not at compile time. The modifiers are only for compile-time checking. Also see previous comment about typescript adding the property to the class when there is a modifier